# Permutation with fixed source in R?

Tags: r, permutation, stringr

I've got a dataset that looks like this:

```
col1 | col2
a | b c d
e | f g h i j
```

I know the permutations function from gtool :

```
p <- (permutations(n=4,r=2,v=df),repeats.allowed=FALSE)
```

can extract the different permutations with or without repetition, but I need column 1 to stay in place, so that the expected outcome would be:

```
a b
a c
a d
e f
e g
e h
e i
e j
```

The documentation doesn't specify how to accomplish something like this. The second vector is variable length and I'll be using str_extract_all to pull them out.

Has anyone seen a way to accomplish the above? The intended outcome is an edge file to be used for network graphing.

Comment: Can provide an example of your data? E.g. via `dput(df)` so we can run the code?

Comment: Larger dataframe ex: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49997931/create-all-possible-column-permutations-in-r-dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `tidyr::separate_rows`:

```
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  separate_rows(col2, sep = " ")

  col1 col2
1    a    b
2    a    c
3    a    d
4    e    f
5    e    g
6    e    h
7    e    i
8    e    j
```

Data:

```
df <- read.table(text = "col1  col2
  a  'b c d'
  e  'f g h i j'",  header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```