# First and last name permutation in datasets

Tags: r, dplyr, permutation

I have a dataset (nearly 26,000 rows) where I have the first and last names in each column as shown below:

```
Id       Name  Firstname1 Firstname2 Firstname3 
 1       AL      BE          GAM       ZET
2        IO      PA          TA        MA
```

I want all possible permutations of the first and last names in the result column as follows:

```
Id Name Firstname1 Firstname2 Firstname3 Result1 Result2...   Resultatn 
1  AL    BE       GAM         ZET    ALBEGAMZET ALBEZETGAM   GAMZETBEAL
2   IO    PA     TA           ME       IOPATAME  IOPAMETA     TAMEPAIO
```

Thanks for your help!

I've tried this but I'm looking for help to generalize

```
df$result1<-paste(df$Name, df$Firstname1,df$Firstname2,df$Firstname3)

df$result2<-paste(df$Name, df$Firstname1,df$Firstname3,df$Firstname2)
```

Comment: Do you mean any order of the four name segments (4 x 3 x 2 x 1 = 24 permutations), or are there other rules which eliminate some combinations (e.g. never starts with Firstname3) or add others (e.g. perhaps only three of the name segments could be used, not all four)?

Comment: @JonSpring yes any order of the four name segment.

Comment: This question seems pretty similar, does this work for you? https://stackoverflow.com/a/49998848/6851825

Comment: @JonSpring It doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create the permutations of the columns with `combinat::permn` or `gtools::permutations`. Then, for each combination, you can paste the columns together in the specified oder.

```
df1 <- tribble(
  ~Id       ,~Name  ,~Firstname1 ,~Firstname2 ,~Firstname3, 
  1   ,    "AL"   ,   "BE"    ,      "GAM"   ,    "ZET",
  2   ,     "IO"  ,    "PA"    ,      "TA"    ,    "MA",
)

options <- combinat::permn(colnames(df1)[-(1:2)])

df2 <- map_dfc(options, ~ pmap_chr(df1[,c("Name", .x)], ~ paste0(..., collapse = ""))) %>%
  set_names(paste0("Result", 1:length(options))) %>%
  bind_cols(df1, .)
```

So for each `option` `.x`, we are selecting the columns of the dataframe in that order (`df1[,c("Name", .x)]`), and pasting their rows together.

Comment: The "Name" column should also be one of the columns to be swapped. I've modified the code slightly options <- combinat::permn(colnames(df1)[-1]) df2 <- map_dfc(options, ~ pmap_chr(df1[, .x], ~ paste0(..., collapse = ""))) %>% set_names(paste0("Result", 1:length(options))) %>% bind_cols(df1, .) Thanks a lot! @Ricardo Semião e Castro